# Base-free proof: Set of generators is Zariski-open

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{k}$ (algebraically closed for simplicity), and let $G$ be a finite group acting on $V$. Then the set of elements $v \in V$ such that $\{ gv : g \in G \}$ generates $V$ is Zariski-open.

By identifying $V = \mathbb{k}^d$ and $G \leq \mathrm{GL}(d,\mathbb{k})$ this statement is easy to prove, since $v \in V$ is a non-generator if and only if all $d$-th minors of a matrix with columns $gv$, $g \in G$ vanish (these minors are polynomials in the coefficients of $v$).

I wonder if there is also an abstract proof of that statement, where we do not need to consider bases of $V$ or matrices at all. I know that the Zariski-topology on $V$ can be defined without referring to a basis by declaring the common vanishing sets of elements of $\operatorname{Sym}(V^*)$ to be closed. The property that $v \in V$ is not a generator can be stated in a base-free fashion by $g_1v \wedge \dots \wedge g_dv = 0$ in $V^{\wedge d}$ for all $d$-subsets $\{g_1, \dots, g_d\} \subseteq G$. Can we show abstractly (i.e. without referring to a basis) that each of those equations describes a zero set of some $f \in \operatorname{Sym}(V^*)$? Or is there an even better way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote?

Comment: How do you propose to write down equations if you don't have a basis?

Comment: @ZhenLin: What exactly do you mean? Equations can be written down in terms of $f(v) = 0$ for $f \in \operatorname{Sym}(V^*)$. Maybe I do need a basis at some point for defining certain elements of $V^*$, but I hope it is possible to avoid this by using abstract results like e.g. “zero sets of multilinear maps are Zariski-closed” (which may be proved by using bases).

Comment: I don't think you can really say you are "writing down equations" if you don't explicitly define $f$...